# TinyMCE: How do I setup the editor to start in plain text mode by default?

Tags: tinymce

So far when I open the page where the editor is, it starts in wysiwyg mode. I want to change that so the plain text mode is shown on start. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "plain text"? just the regular textarea (no tinymce then)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the editor instance when the page opens so that it opens in plain 
text mode.

You can add it later on.
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/s1caab)